# Next js dynamic pathname routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js

For example, there is a pathname that comes to me as **/example/123** and I need to redirect it to **/otherExample/123**.

I am using next/router. and I am getting urli coming as router.asPath.

```
if(router.asPath == '/example/123') {
   Router.push('/otherExample/123')
}
```

I don't know how to do it because 123 part is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using next's redirect functionality. You can read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#path-matching).

In `next.config.js` add the `redirects` key:

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/example/:slug',
        destination: '/otherExample/:slug',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
```

If you want the redirect to be cached forever, set permanent to true. Otherwise, you should set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

Just cut the last part of the path and use it down :

```
const pathParts = path.split('/');
const exampleId = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1];
Router.push(`/otherExample/${exampleId}`);
```

Or easire just use router.query to get the value of the parameter :

```
const { exampleId } = router.query;
if (exampleId) {
  Router.push(`/otherExample/${exampleId}`);
}
```